# Xamarin.Forms: Unwanted Behavior of Master-Detail Menu/Hamburger button

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, master-detail

I'm running the default Master Detail app for Xamarin.Forms which shows the Menu/Master button on the top left.

[image]

And this is how it looks when I rotate it to landscape.

[image]

When I drill down into detail page while in Landscape...

[image]

Then I rotate the device to portrait mode on this page.

[image]

Everything is working as expected until I press back button from this page.

[image]

You might see it is missing the Master/menu button(or the hamburger button). Am I missing anything here?

**SCREEN RECORDING**
[image: Screen Recording]

Comment: What version of XF are you using? Looks like this bug in potential: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/4506

Comment: @GeraldVersluis I'm using 3.6.0.293080.

Comment: Can you add the relevant code?

Comment: @G.hakim It's the default template "Master-Details Form App" created through Visual Studio Community.

Comment: Here is link to the codebase just in case: https://github.com/rails-hub/MasterDetailTest

Comment: Do you repeat this every time? I tried it on my side but it didn't come back

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT Didn't repeat this, it happens on the very first go and happens every time. Important thing to note is that I'm using 
MasterBehavior = MasterBehavior.SplitOnLandscape;
as master behavior and this is iOS specific.

Comment: Added the screen recording to make explain it more.

Comment: yes,i hava report it to official github